# Socialite stateless auth

Tags: php, angular, laravel, facebook-authentication, laravel-socialite

I have a front-end SPA built on Angular 6 and back-end on Laravel 5.6. I'm trying to make a facebook auth using `ngx-social-login` on the front-end and a `Socialite` on the back-end.

That is code in my component

```
signInWithFacebook(): void {
  this.sas.signIn(FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then(
    userData => this.as.fb(userData.authToken).subscribe(x => {
      console.log(x);
    })
  );
}
```

And this is a service

```
fb(data): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.API_URL, data);
}
```

And here is my Laravel routes

```
$api->version('v1', function ($api) {
    $api->get('auth/facebook', 'SocialAuthFacebookController@redirectToProvider');
    $api->get('auth/facebook/callback', 'SocialAuthFacebookController@callback');
});
```

That is a controller

```
public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->redirect();
    }

    public function callback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();

        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, 'facebook');

        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($authUser);

        return Response::json(compact('token'));
    }

    public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
    {
        $authUser = User::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();

        if ($authUser) {
            return $authUser;
        }

        return User::create([
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'provider' => $provider,
            'provider_id' => $user->id
        ]);
    }
```

Since I'm using Laravel as an API-only so I suppose that I cannot access `redirectToProvider` so that I tried to call `auth/facebook/callback` and pass it an `authToken` that I get after a login on my SPA. However, it doesn't seem to work.

I'm experiencing the next error
[image]

Thanks to Facebook there is so much information so that I don't know what's wrong and what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that might help:

```
    /**
     * Redirect the user to the Facebook authentication page.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from Facebook.
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $providerUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();

        $user = User::query()->firstOrNew(['email' => $providerUser->getEmail()]);

        if (!$user->exists) {
            $user->name = $providerUser->getName();
            $user->save(); 
        }

        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

        return new JsonResponse([
            'token' => $token
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: what is the benefit of returning a token from the callback method as opposed to redirecting to a view such as a homepage?